# TableView reloadData right after deleteRows

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

In my `tableView`, I delete a row and right after that I need to reload the whole table to recalculate some values. What is the best way to do it? Since `deleteRows` does not have a completion handler and, according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41525912/10043836) on SO, I should never call `tableView.reloadData()` right after deleting a row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { [weak self] (action, view, completion) in
            guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
            
            CoreDataManager.manager.deleteActivity(activity: weakSelf.sortedActivites[indexPath.row])
            weakSelf.sortedActivites.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.reloadData()
            completion(true)
        }
        
      deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        
      return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only calling `reloadData` is enough in your case.

If you need a completion callback for the `deleteRows`, you may want to try calling `deleteRows` with `none` animation inside a `UIView.animate` block.

```
UIView.animate(
  withDuration: 0.2,
  animations: {
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
  },
  completion: { _ in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  })
```

Comment: true, but then i do not have a deleting animation. it is not a big problem, but i would be just interested in how to do it the way i described

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`. This is a new thing that Apple showed us in iOS 13. With this API you receive some great benefits that declarative programming has and could potentially eliminate a whole class of very common bugs found in many different apps.

If your app is built for devices 13.0+, you can give it a try. This will handle for you things like delete, insert, etc. So all you need to do, is create a new snapshot just right after you deleted your activity from `CoreDataManager` and apply it to `dataSource`.

`dataSource.apply (someSnapshot, animatingDifferences: true, Completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `reloadSections()`?

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0...0), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.top)
```